# Searching for number of repeated patterns in text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, numpy, python-requests

I wanted to know any suggestions on a code which I can use to output the number of found patterns in a text file.

Example: I have a text file with `("ABBAABBBAAABAB")` and I want to search for a certain pattern like `("ABA")` but I dont want it to count the last letter as part of the pattern, only new letters.

I've tried using `split()` and `count()` but it seems to give me numbers found on each line instead of the entire file and when I dont use `split()` to put it into a list it just prints 0.

Example its giving me this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

And when split it kind of works but doesnt give me the sum only for each line for example:

```
23
32
12
20
15
```

How can i get the sum of the pattern im searching for in the entire file just one number like 150 etc...

Would really appreciate some help thank you

Comment: Please post your code snippet

Comment: `but I dont want it to count the last letter as part of the pattern, only new letters` unable to understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you give an example for the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
input_text = 'ABBAABBBAAABAB'
pattern = 'ABA'
# removing last letter
input_text = input_text[:-1]
result = len([*re.finditer(pattern, input_text)])
```

Result will have the desired count.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re
 data="ABBAABBBAAABABABA"
 matches=re.finditer(r"(ABA)+",data)
 for match in matches:
      print(match)
```

output:

```
 <re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match='ABA'>
 <re.Match object; span=(14, 17), match='ABA'>
```